# Pivot specific column values using any efficient method

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, sql-server-2016

I have a table which has a sample data as shown below.

[image]

I'm trying to create a pivoted table as shown below from the above table.

[image]

so basically I need to move the "catalogID" in the attname column to a new column with its value. (based on the grouping/matching of uploadguid and equipmentRef column values)

I was able to achieve the result using the given script , yet I think that't not the efficient way to do this, if anyone has the better idea, I would appreciate your help.

Here is the SQL fiddle for this one.

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #temp1
(
uploadguid varchar(50) NULL,
attname varchar(50) NULL,
attvalue varchar(50) NULL,
equipmentRef varchar(50) NULL,
)   

Insert Into #temp1 
Values (N'651EF',N'Impact',N'0.123459',N'43398E')
,(N'651EF',N'CatalogID',N'12456',N'43398E')
,(N'541EF',N'alpha',N'0.547623',N'43398E')
,(N'541EF',N'CatalogID',N'36592',N'43398E')
,(N'921EF',N'Beta',N'0.44875',N'43398E')
,(N'921EF',N'CatalogID',N'25894',N'43398E')

Select * from #temp1

select a.*,b.DBcatalogID from #temp1 a inner join (SELECT uploadguid,[CatalogID] AS [DBcatalogID]
        FROM  (select top 100 uploadguid,attname,attvalue,equipmentRef from #temp1 ) a
        PIVOT (max(attvalue) FOR attname IN  ([CatalogID]) ) p) b ON a.uploadguid = b.uploadguid
        WHERE a.attname <> 'CatalogID'

--Drop table #temp1
END
```

Comment: Your query is simple enough, I doubt it can be tuned up. Maybe you should try to change the table definition if you want to store it this way (with DBCatalogID as column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.attvalue as DBcatalogID
from #temp1 t1
    join #temp1 t2 on t1.uploadguid = t2.uploadguid and 
                      t1.equipmentRef = t2.equipmentRef and 
                      t2.attname = 'CatalogID'
where t1.attname != 'CatalogID'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select *, tt.attvalue as DBCatid
from #temp1 t cross apply (
     select top 1 t1.attvalue
     from #temp1 t1
     where t1.uploadguid = t.uploadguid and t1.attname = 'CatalogID'
) tt
where t.attname <> 'CatalogID';
```